# How to I make unique input filed value inside looped array in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to update specific inputfield / selectfield value in React.
Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'






  const FoodScreen = () => {
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(0)

      return (
        <div className='row gy-2'>
          {filteredProducts &&
            filteredProducts.map((product) => (
              <div key={product._id} className='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12'>
                <div className='card icon-card'>
                  <div className='card-body'>
                    <div className='card-title text-center'>{product.name}</div>
                    <div className='card-text text-center'>
                      <div className='btn-group'>
                        <span
                          className='p-1 rounded-pill shadow-none'
                          style={{ color: '#f46c2d' }}
                        >
                          ${product.price}
                        </span>
    
                        <select
                          className='btn border-1 border-success btn-sm shadow-none mx-1'
                          name='qty'
                          value={qty}
                          onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}
                        >
                          <option value='0' disabled='disabled'>
                            QTY
                          </option>
                          {[...Array(10).keys()].map((x) => (
                            <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                              {x + 1}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                        </select>
    
                        <FaMinus
                          className='bg-dark p-2 text-light fs-3 rounded-pill mx-1'
                          style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                          onClick={() => removeFromCurrentHandler(product)}
                        />
                        <FaPlus
                          onClick={() => addToCartHandler(product)}
                          className='bg-dark p-2 text-light fs-3 rounded-pill mx-1'
                          style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default FoodScreen
```

The issue  I'm having now is if I change the value of one selectfiled / input field the other loopped selectfield are changing because the ara using **value={qty}**. How do I make it. I don't have any concept.

this is, what is making duplication.

```
name='qty'
value={qty}
onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}
```

Comment: Why is there a node.js tag to this ?

Comment: sorry if I did wrong but I'm using MERN Stack

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on how to ask a good question before posting a question !

Answer (score 0):

Use key as index of the map so  it will take specific index at the time of editing

```
filteredProducts &&
        filteredProducts.map((product, index) => (
          <div key={index} className='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12'>
```